# Hide some element from printing by client side on web

Tags: html, browser

Let's say I log into facebook but I don't want the "likes" to appear when the page is rendering.

Again: I open a photo from my friend. Under the pic there's a element that says "Somefriend, someotherfriend and 123123 persons like this".

I don't want that to appear.

I think it can be achieved by writing some script (plugin, addon) for my browser, maybe in Firefox with firebug or in Chrome with it's built in code inspector...

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: This is relatively easy to do with your own extension. That said, there's an existing extension, [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/), which offers lots of customization, filters, etc for facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily implement such functionality using browsers' extensions (add-ons). In order to do so, read their official tutorials. We can't give you exact solution because it differs among browsers. One thing will be similar though - they all use Javascript for page manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Every browser comes with a built-in CSS style sheet. Simply goto the `Developer Tools` or press `Ctrl-Shift-I` on most browsers and check out the `user agent stylesheet`. The trick is to find this stylesheet in your installation folder and add whatever elements you want to hide and adding `!important` so it overrides everything.